# WinJS Issues | Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, winjs, winrt-component

I am a C# windows developer. I recently started to work with WinJS. Working with WinJS, I have noticed some challenges and limitations. Can face some new challenges as the community support for WinJS is very less. Below are the few points mentioned regarding this concern

a. WinJS does not support Visual Studio features like Finding References of Classes and Variables which is very useful to code productively.

b. WinJS is not strongly typed as C#. So we will get to know about the errors at runtime only instead of compile time which is difficult to Debug and time taking process.

c. WinJS does not support feature “What you see is what you get”. Visual Studio designer is not available for WinJS. We can see the application design only after we run the application which is again time taking thing.

There are very less chances of availability of “Ready to Work on WinJS” resources. Because most of the developers in Windows community work on C#, XAML languages.

d. Direct compatibility of third party libraries for WinJS might not be available.

Have anybody experience in WinJS and faced similar issues? Or Are there any solutions exists for this? What is the scope of improvement in Windows 10 version for WinJS??

Answer (score 0):

For an HTML/CSS/JS designer, that's what Blend for Visual Studio is for. Load the project into Blend and you'll get a designer that also works when you're running the app. Documentation for this is on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj129478.aspx, and there's a great video from //build 2013 that shows the flow, http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/2-311. I also cover using Blend to some extent in my free ebook, [*Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, 2nd Edition*](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2).

Answer (score -2):

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/winjs
see this link it give the solution your problem which is given below

a. WinJS does not support Visual Studio features like Finding References of Classes and Variables which is very useful to code productively.

b. WinJS is not strongly typed as C#. So we will get to know about the errors at runtime only instead of compile time which is difficult to Debug and time taking process.

c. WinJS does not support feature “What you see is what you get”. Visual Studio designer is not available for WinJS. We can see the application design only after we run the application which is again time taking thing.

Comment: It does not answering any query. It is just a basic documentation to get started with WinJS. It is not giving any info regarding these loopholes.